# AttributeError at /coordinator 'Coordinator' object has no attribute 'agent'

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-queryset

Expected Outcome: I want to query the parent objects which are relevant to the coordinator. Please help on how I can achieve such.

The Error is occuring after running the following queryset,

```
user.coordinator.agent.parent_set.all()
```

Models

```
class Coordinator(models.Model):
user = OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL) 
region = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True, choices=REGION)
id_no = id_no = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
address = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
gender = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False, choices=GENDER)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Agent(models.Model):
user = OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
coordinator = models.ForeignKey(Coordinator, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=SET_NULL)
region = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True, choices=REGION)
id_no = id_no = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False, blank=False, unique=True,)
address = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
gender = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False, choices=GENDER)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Parent(models.Model):
   agent = models.ForeignKey(Agent, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=SET_NULL)
   surname = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False, blank=False)
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False, blank=False)
   other_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
   address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
   region = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True, choices=REGION)
   dob = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, blank=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `user.coordinator.agent.parent_set.all()` because there is no direct relation between `coordinator` and `agent`. You should do this instead :

```py
# Starting from a Coordinator
coordinator.user.agent.parent_set.all()
# Starting from a user
user.agent.parent_set.all()
```

Note that this could raise exceptions as your OneToOneFields are nullable.

You'd have to change your models to get your query working as follows :

```py
class Agent(models.Model):
    coordinator = OneToOneField(Coordinator, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    # Instead of 
    user = OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```